# Print all possibles Longest Decreasing Subsequence

Tags: c++, algorithm

I had array of integers A[1...N].Now i want to print ALL LONGEST DECREASING SUBSEQUENCE. I had went through most of the tutorial ,but all tutorials prints only one LDS.Suppose the length of LDS is 5 ,then most of them only prints one LDS of length 5.
But i want to print all the possible LDS.How to do this??Can it be done in O(nlongn)time.Pseudocode will be more helpful.

Comment: What tutorial? What have you come with so far? Any code where you have a specific question?

Comment: Try thinking of verious datastructure to use, post some sample code, show what you have tried etc. basically _TRIE_

Comment: @Femaref:https://comeoncodeon.wordpress.com/2009/08/12/longest-increasing-subsequence-lis/ this what i refered.This is though LIS but that won't mattaer a lot.It prints only the LAST LDS if multiples exits.I want to print all of the LDS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to understand the idea if you un-optimizer the algorithm from your tutorial, and use a simpler `N^2` algorithm that searches back linearly instead of looking up in the map. Then modify the code that prints the sequence to search for prior element backward rather than storing it in the `vector<int> pre`. Then you could print all sequences with a simple recursive backtracker:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void print_all(
    const vector<int> seq
,   const vector<int>& len
,   int max, int pos
,   vector<int>& sofar) {
    if (max == 0) {
        for (int i = sofar.size()-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
            cout << sofar[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;
        return;
    }
    int val = pos < seq.size() ? seq[pos] : -1;
    for (int i = pos-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if (len[i] == max && seq[i] > val) {
            sofar.push_back(seq[i]);
            print_all(seq, len, max-1, i, sofar);
            sofar.erase(sofar.end()-1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int data[] = {5, 30, 2, 17, 92, 11, 7, 10, 2, 1};
    vector<int> seq(data, data+10);
    vector<int> len(seq.size());
    for (int i = 0 ; i < seq.size() ; i++) {
        len[i] = 1;
        for (int j = i-1 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
            if (seq[j] > seq[i] && len[j]+1 > len[i])
                len[i] = len[j]+1;
    }
    int max = *max_element(len.begin(), len.end());
    cerr << max << endl;
    vector<int> sofar;
    print_all(seq, len, max, seq.size(), sofar);
}
```

Comment: dasblinkenlight::The program is giving incorrect output for case data[]={5, 23, 100, 10 ,4 ,90, 65, 11 ,18, 10} its giving LDS length=4,and LDS are
{90 65 18 10},
{90 65 11 10}
How ever the correct answer is LDS length=5,and LDS are
{100 90 65 18 10},
{100 90 65 11 10}

Comment: dasblinkenlight::The program is giving incorrect output for case data[]={5, 23, 100, 10 ,4 ,90, 65, 11 ,18, 10} its giving LDS length=4,and LDS are {90 65 18 10}, {90 65 11 10} How ever the correct answer is LDS length=5,and LDS are {100 90 65 18 10}, {100 90 65 11 10}

Comment: @JohnGreve This should now be [fixed](http://ideone.com/14o1Z) - the code wasn't catching the largest element in the middle of the sequence.

Comment: dasblinkenlight::thanks a lot.I just want to ask a last question,where should i modify your code if i don't want strictly decreasing ,i mean i want longest decreasing(Not strictly ) subsequence . I mean data[]={100 ,2 ,100 ,3} should give answer {100,100,3}.Thanks!

Comment: @JohnGreve Since the code makes the "is in the correct order" decision when calculating the length and when printing the sequence, you should replace `>` with `>=` in two places: `seq[j] > seq[i]` and `seq[i] > val`.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of all your longest (so far) subsequences as you go along:

```
// If you have only one element, that is the longest descending subsequence
// Otherwise store first element as previous

if: current element is less than (or equal to) previous
  // decreasing
  increase current subsequence length
  add element to current subsequence
else:
  // increasing
  set current subsequence length to 0
  empty current subsequence

if: current subsequence is longer than current maximum
  invalidate all current max subsequences
  set current maximum subsequence length to current subsequence length
  add current subsequence to set of longest subsequences
else if: current subsequence is same size as current maximum
  add current subsequence to set of longest subsequences
```